# Split list of strings into list of sublists based on a string

Tags: python, string, list

This problem is most easily illustrated in pseudo-code. I have a list like this:

```
linelist = ["a", "b", "", "c", "d", "e", "", "a"]
```

I would like to get it in the format:

```
questionchunks = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["a"]]
```

My first attempt is this:

```
questionchunks = []
qlist = []

for line in linelist:

    if (line != "" and len(qlist) != 0 ):
        questionchunks.append(qlist)
        qlist = []
    else: 
        qlist.append(line)
```

My output is a little messed up though. I'd be grateful for any pointers I can get.

Comment: some of the answers rely on the array contents being contiguous, I suspect that isn't true in your real use case?

Comment: @stevejpurves - The array contents will always be contiguous in that they will have groups of non-empty strings separated by empty strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost near your goal, this is the minimal edit required

```
linelist = ["a", "b", "", "c", "d", "e", "", "a"]
questionchunks = []
qlist = []
linelist.append('') # append an empty str at the end to avoid the other condn
for line in linelist:

    if (line != "" ):
        questionchunks.append(line)      # add the element to each of your chunk   
    else: 
        qlist.append(questionchunks)   # append chunk
        questionchunks = []       # reset chunk

print qlist
```

Comment: I am not sure what's OP desired output for something like: `["", "a", "b", "", "c", "d", "e", "", "a", ""]`, but this solution will add empty lists for this example.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for that info. It does add empty lists, but isn't it just easy to remove them in one line ? Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

This can be easily done using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> linelist = ["a", "b", "", "c", "d", "e", "", "a"]
>>> split_at = ""
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(linelist, lambda x: x != split_at) if k]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['a']]
```